# Core Data related issue

Tags: iphone, ios, core-data

I'm downloading content from a server and save it in a SQLite database managed with the CoreData Framework. It works, but I have an occasional crash that I don't understand. Here is my crash report :

```
Thread 5 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.root.default-priority
Thread 5 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x38eca5b6 objc_msgSend + 22
1   CoreData                        0x30fe354c getValueCore + 24
2   CoreData                        0x30fe34fa _PFCMT_GetValue + 6
3   CoreData                        0x30fe346a -[NSManagedObjectContext(_NSInternalAdditions) _retainedObjectWithID:optionalHandler:withInlineStorage:] + 34
4   CoreData                        0x30fe6ece -[_NSFaultingMutableSet willRead] + 394
5   CoreData                        0x30fe7518 -[_NSFaultingMutableSet member:] + 84
6   CoreFoundation                  0x3119aa50 -[NSSet countForObject:] + 16
7   CoreFoundation                  0x3123a9f4 -[NSSet isSubsetOfSet:] + 516
8   Foundation                      0x31b2a902 NSKeyValueWillChangeBySetMutation + 406
9   Foundation                      0x31ac2c48 NSKeyValueWillChange + 404
10  Foundation                      0x31b2a760 -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:] + 260
11  CoreData                        0x3101e71c -[NSManagedObject willChangeValueForKey:withSetMutation:usingObjects:] + 80
12  CoreData                        0x31022f26 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _excludeObject:fromPropertyWithKey:andIndex:] + 626
13  CoreData                        0x31023df4 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _maintainInverseRelationship:forProperty:oldDestination:newDestination:] + 228
14  CoreData                        0x31024622 -[NSManagedObject(_NSInternalMethods) _didChangeValue:forRelationship:named:withInverse:] + 1286
15  CoreData                        0x3102dc3e -[NSManagedObjectContext observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:] + 318
16  Foundation                      0x31ac36b4 NSKeyValueNotifyObserver + 268
17  Foundation                      0x31ac330e NSKeyValueDidChange + 330
18  Foundation                      0x31a9d6ce -[NSObject(NSKeyValueObserverNotification) didChangeValueForKey:] + 90
19  CoreData                        0x3101e234 _PF_ManagedObject_DidChangeValueForKeyIndex + 100
20  CoreData                        0x310287b2 _sharedIMPL_setvfk_core + 222
21  Instabay                        0x000bf3a0 -[AdGetMemberStuffsWSProxy processData:] (AdGetMemberStuffsWSProxy.m:101)
22  Instabay                        0x000a7328 -[IBAbstractWSProxy didReceiveData:] (IBAbstractWSProxy.m:437)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x312389c0 __invoking___ + 64
24  CoreFoundation                  0x3118ffe6 -[NSInvocation invoke] + 282
25  Foundation                      0x31b38b60 -[NSInvocationOperation main] + 108
26  Foundation                      0x31ac25bc -[__NSOperationInternal start] + 836
27  Foundation                      0x31b3abde __block_global_6 + 98
28  libdispatch.dylib               0x392e711c _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 8
29  libdispatch.dylib               0x392f5254 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 256
30  libdispatch.dylib               0x392f53b4 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 80
31  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3931ba0e _pthread_wqthread + 358
32  libsystem_c.dylib               0x3931b8a0 start_wqthread + 4
```

And also the method where the crash occurs :

```
- (id) processData:(id)theData
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *moc = self.backgroundMOC;

    // Fetch Members
    NSDictionary *existingMembersMap = [[IBWSUtils fetchExistingMembersListBy:@"memberId"
                                                       inManagedObjectContext:moc]
                                        retain];

    // Fetch existing Ads (we only need the Id to build our cache mapping)
    NSDictionary *existingAdsMap = [[IBWSUtils fetchExistingAdsListInManagedObjectContext:moc] retain];

    IBMember *member = (IBMember *)[moc objectWithID:self.memberObjectID];

    // Purge existing results, otherwise leave as is and simply append to the bottom
    if (! self.shouldAppendResults)
    {
        if (member.stuffs != nil) {
            [member removeStuffs:member.stuffs];
        }
//        member.stuffs = nil;
    }

    // Sets total number of ads
    member.stuffsCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[theData integerForKey:@"quantity"]];

    NSArray *ads = [theData objectForKey:@"ad"];

    for (NSDictionary *adDict in ads)
    {
        if ([adDict isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {
            continue;
        }

//        @autoreleasepool
        {
            NSString *currentAdId = [adDict objectForKey:@"id"];

            // Get existing ad copy
            IBAd *currentAd = [existingAdsMap objectForKey:currentAdId];

            if (!currentAd)
            {
                // Otherwise, create a new ad instance
                currentAd = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Ad"
                                                          inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                currentAd.adId = currentAdId;
                currentAd.creationDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSince1970:[[adDict nonNullValueForKeyPath:@"createdAt.sec"] floatValue]];
            }

            currentAd.adDescription = [adDict objectForKey:@"description"];

            // If member instance doesn't exist, create a new one
            NSString *memberId = [adDict nonNullValueForKeyPath:@"seller.memberId"];
            IBMember *existingMember = [existingMembersMap objectForKey:memberId];
            if (!existingMember)
            {
                existingMember = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Member"
                                                               inManagedObjectContext:moc];

                existingMember.memberId = memberId;
                existingMember.userName = [adDict nonNullValueForKeyPath:@"seller.memberName"];
            }

            **// The line below is the line 101 that causes the crash
            currentAd.member = existingMember;**

            @try {
                currentAd.mediaURI = [[[adDict objectForKey:@"media"] objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"uri"];
            }
            @catch (NSException *exception) {
                currentAd.mediaURI = nil;
            }

            IBWanted *wants = currentAd.wants;
            if (!wants)
            {
                // Otherwise, create a new ad instance
                wants = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Wanted"
                                                      inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                currentAd.wants = wants;
            }

            wants.count = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:[adDict integerForKey:@"followWanted"]];

            [member addStuffsObject:currentAd];
        }
    }

    // Save operation
    [self saveBackgroundManagedObjectContext];

    [existingAdsMap release];
    [existingMembersMap release];

    return nil;
}
```

I don't know what I did wrong.

** EDIT **
This bug occurs only on device. No problem with the simulator.

Comment: Are you that you perform operations with context in the thread this context use? If no, `[moc.performBlock:^{ /*fetch and save*/ }];`

Comment: It seems so. I'm using the same managedObjectContext to perform the save operation. Then I post a notification to the main thread to execute the "mergeChangesFromContextDidSaveNotification:" method